# SDK 4.2 UIWebView Error

Tags: ios, uiwebview, xcode4.2, uitabbar, storyboard

Thought that I did my homework, and 4 days of it was enough, so here it is.  Simple as it may be I am just trying to connect a Storyboard Tab View Controller to a web address for each Tab (noob here).  There are a lot of codes out there and all of them have not worked.  I have been everywhere learning what not to do.  This is an X-mas present for the family to view our personal websites.

Goal:
  TabBarView (with Storyboard)
   - 4 Tabs (each a UIWebView)

I do know how to connect the UIWebView - ViewController and the ViewController - File's Owner

In the .h I have done:

{

IBOutlet IUWebView *google;

}

The .m string is driving me crazy though, none of the post for IOS 5 have worked.

Please Help.  I have been working on this for 3 weeks and have learned a lot.  Also if there is any reference on Xcode tutorials besides the Dev Center would be much appreciated.

Comment: So just so I am on the same line of thought here - you simply want a plain app with 4 tab bars that only show a UIWebView? or you want other features? - you set a default page for each of these tabs to go to.

Comment: I voted this back to zero - yes it may be a basic question, but we all have to learn and what he has typed is a start. It would be good if he wrote it in a code block though.

Answer (score 0):

By what you have posted, you need to write UIWebView first (may have been a typo on your part) also you need to include the UIWebViewDelegate in your header file.

```
{
IBOutlet IUWebView *google;
}
```

should be :

```
{
IBOutlet UIWebView *google;
}
```

Let me know if I can help any further.
-Jeff